# Android, trying to move Eclipse project to a different workspace

Tags: android, project

I used the import export in Eclipse to copy my android project to another workspace.  All the files show up with the same folder structure.  Now when I try to run it, I get a 
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error one.
I tried to clean it, but got the same response.

Comment: Is R.java in the gen folder updated? You may need to open and save the resource xml files.

Comment: Did you export using the file system, and archive, or and android application?

Comment: Hi,I erase the r file to make it creat a new one.  Also I did the inport and export within the ide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend importing projects into another workspace by creating a new Android Project (in the new workspace) and then checking "Create project from existing source"

I have found the Eclipse Import functionality to be very unreliable with android projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy the entire project directory from one workspace to the other. As long as there are no external dependencies (android library projects, other projects) it should work just fine. You can remove the bin and gen directories in the new copy and they should be recreated.

Comment: Hi,I rtried to do this, and the work space I copied it to did nnot see the new project

Comment: After you copy the directory you have to import it. File->Import->General->Existing projects into Workspace->Next->Select your workspace dir as the "Root Directory". Your project should appear in the list of projects.

Comment: @JohnnyLambada, I think that your answer could help me on this other question that I asked; `http://stackoverflow.com/q/9559932/410975`. I must avoid copying files which contradict the paths set up in the other computer I am copying project files to, but I need to do this frequently so want it possible in few steps. So could I simply `export` the project to a directory, copy that onto the other computer and import it into the workspace to overwrite the previous workspace? I do not want multiple copies. thanks

Comment: Your best bet is to use the answers that were already given for your question. Use a version control system. Bitbucket.org is free and has ample space for private projects -- there is just no good reason not to use a version control system.